# Tensorflow merge dimensions and reverse merge

Tags: python, tensorflow

Assume I have a tensor with shape `[3, 5, 200, 300, 3]`. How can I merge first two dim together so that I have tensor with shape `[15, 200, 300, 3]`? Then I should be able to reverse merge operation and have original shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just use `tf.reshape`

```
a = tf.random_normal(shape=(3, 5, 200, 300, 3))
b = tf.reshape(a, shape=(15, 200, 300, 3))
...
c = tf.reshape(b, shape=(3, 5, 200, 300, 3))
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the number of dimensions when we do not know the exact shape? (Or should we call tf.reshape with tf.shape inside?)

Comment: @Khaj You can use symbolic dimensions with `tf.reshape`, so yes, what you describe would work (however, assembling that symbolic shape is sometimes complicated). If there's only one unknown dimension then you can infer it automatically by specifying -1, for example: `tf.reshape(b, shape=(-1, 20, 30))`.

Answer (score 2):

The following functions merge and split the first two dimensions of a tensor, inference the static or dynamic shape of it.

```
def infer_shape(x):
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)

    # If unknown rank, return dynamic shape
    if x.shape.dims is None:
        return tf.shape(x)

    static_shape = x.shape.as_list()
    dynamic_shape = tf.shape(x)

    ret = []
    for i in range(len(static_shape)):
        dim = static_shape[i]
        if dim is None:
            dim = dynamic_shape[i]
        ret.append(dim)

    return ret

def merge_first_two_dims(tensor):
    shape = infer_shape(tensor)
    shape[0] *= shape[1]
    shape.pop(1)
    return tf.reshape(tensor, shape)


def split_first_two_dims(tensor, dim_0, dim_1):
    shape = infer_shape(tensor)
    new_shape = [dim_0] + [dim_1] + shape[1:]
    return tf.reshape(tensor, new_shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most generically, you can do this, which does not rely on a having static shape:

```
a = tf.ones([3, 5, 200, 300, 3])
b = tf.reshape(a, tf.concat([[tf.shape(a)[0] * tf.shape(a)[1]], tf.shape(a)[2:]], axis=0))
```